# How to define the Authorization header with a custom prefix in OpenAPI 3?

Tags: authorization, openapi

I am looking for the proper way to specify an `Authorization` header with a custom type/prefix like "ApiKey" in OpenAPI 3.

The custom `Authorization` header should look like

```
Authorization: ApiKey myAPIKeyHere
```

All my attempts to specify the `securitySchemes` entry with `type: apiKey` seems to
produce other results...

The closest I got is something like:

```yaml
securitySchemes:
  ApiKeyAuth:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: ApiKey
```

... but this generates the `ApiKey: myAPIKeyHere` header instead of `Authorization: ApiKey myAPIKeyHere`.

How can such a requirement be specified?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I have found a way that seems acceptable - although not perfect. Would like to see something better in the future...

It seems that there is no other way than to add the custom type to the value (aided by a description like below).

```yaml
components:
  securitySchemes:
      ApiKey:
         type: apiKey
         name: Authorization
         in: header
         description: 'Prefix the value with \"ApiKey\" to indicate the custom authorization type' 
security:
   - ApiKey: []
```

This does at least produce the correct header in curl (if applied correctly).

Comment: This is the correct answer. There's no direct way to define a custom prefix for the `Authorization` header (i.e. a prefix that's different from [IANA-registered](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml) HTTP authentication schemes). The workaround is to mention this custom prefix in the description field so that the API consumer will provide this prefix as part of the header value.

Answer (score -2):

Please try this:

```
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKeyAuth:
       type: apiKey
       in: header
       name: ApiKey
  security
    - ApiKeyAuth: []
```

Please have a look at the documentation:

-> Step 2. Applying security

[Authentication and Authorization](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/)

Comment: But doesn't that produce the same result? Only the name is different. I think it is still not placed within the Authorization header....

Comment: @JoeFrizz. Sorry. you're right. I will edit my post

Comment: Ok, probably I am wrong right now but according to the swagger ui editor, this produces the following result: https://pasteboard.co/IPtJnAO.png How does somebody know, that the Authorization header with custom type has to be used?